# xrandr doesn't detect hdmi on ubuntu 20

Tags: drivers, laptop, hdmi, xrandr

i bought new laptop

install ubuntu and connect HDMI...dose not work.

and i found this

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

xrandr doesn't detect hdmi, normally other ubuntu detected HDMI-1 or something
i'm ask on google, that cause is  *-display UNCLAIMED

```
  *-display                 
   description: 3D controller
   product: GP107M [GeForce MX350]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:95 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Renoir
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: c2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

you can see a part of   *-display UNCLAIMED

so i'm looking for amd or ati or renoir or radeon graphic drivers, i did install them, did everying, does not work.

could you solve it?