# HDMI port not detected on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, 20.10

[This question has what I think is a duplicate [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263805/xrandr-doesnt-detect-hdmi-on-ubuntu-20) but I thought it would be worth providing another one with more detail)]

I'm trying to set up an external monitor to my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad L380) but the HDMI port (there is only one on the laptop) is not being detected. I have a dual boot system and the same monitor+HDMI setup works fine on the Windows distro but not on Ubuntu. The `Settings`->`Displays` section does not show multiple displays and it turns out that `xrandr` is not detecting that there is a HDMI port at all. I have tried checking for available driver updates, changing display managers (between `gdm3` and `lightdm` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078539/hdmi-port-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)) but to no avail, the HDMI port doesn't show up for `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr --query
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

nor using `aplay`:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My laptop is using the default Intel graphics card shown below:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

The following is my `xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Driver "intel"
#   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

For further info in case it's useful, here's the output of `xrandr` with the verbosity setting:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x528) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x527
    Timestamp:  12935
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x528) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

and the `sudo lspci -vnn` output related to the VGA controller:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 [17aa:506c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I thought maybe the fact that I/O ports are disabled may have something to do with my problem?